# Como obter o "console output" do Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Utilizo a `REST API` do `Jenkins` para obter todas as informações que preciso com:  `/api/json?pretty=true`.

Agora preciso pegar os logs que estão em `/console`, e gostaria de saber se ele possui algo semelhante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que como o Log é um resultado final bastante genérico, o `Jenkins` disponibiliza ele de forma diferente e simples. E como eu estava buscando um `JSON`, acabei não percebendo isso logo de cara.

Para acessar o log do build, basta acessar o `/consoleText`.